# How to initialise values in one table with a group by from another table in sql

Tags: sql, insert, sql-update, group

I need to use create a column in one table and set the values in the column as groups based on values in another table.

I keep getting this error:

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

And this one:

> ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SRUB0001"."GAME"."GAME_ID")

Here is my code:

```
UPDATE team
SET
    no_players = (
        SELECT
            COUNT(player_id) AS no_players
        FROM game
        GROUP BY game_id
    );
```

Comment: Think very carefully about what you are asking your update to do. The value being assigned to each row for `no_players` is expected to be a *single scalar value*. Your sub query is returning one row per *each set* of grouped rows. Which single one of those many rows should be used? The query optimizer is saying "I dunno". Hint - correlation.

Answer (score 0):

try over() clause to match no of columns in both tables

Comment: Getting this:SQL Error: ORA-00913: too many values

Comment: add "team" and "game" table structures to the problem. without knowing the table structure it is hard to correct your code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).